# iCloud Core Data not syncing

Tags: ios, core-data, upload, icloud

I think I did everything I could find on tutorials and apple's documentation.
But my Core Data do no get out of my iOS device to the iCloud servers.

In short, the following calls are made :

- Get Ubiquity token and check that user wants to use iCloud - done - works OK
- Connect to Ubiquity containers using URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier: - done - though this should be useless (according to a previous discussion thread)
- Registered to receive and handle NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification, NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification, NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification notifications

I do see in the console the messages :
`-[PFUbiquitySwitchboardEntryMetadata setUseLocalStorage:](771): CoreData: Ubiquity:  mobile~xxxx
Using local storage: 1`

and

`-[PFUbiquitySwitchboardEntryMetadata setUseLocalStorage:](771): CoreData: Ubiquity:  mobile~xxxx
Using local storage: 0`

and my handlers are called.

I can use the app perfectly in the iOS device, but **no data is uploaded to iCloud**.

When I delete the app from the device, iOS ask me confirmation if I really want to delete the app, and then asks for a second confirmation because "**some iCloud data is pending upload, and I will loose them**".
I checked that data could be pending for more than 24 hours.
And, of course, my iOS device has network and iCloud is working fine.

Any idea of what I could have done stupidly ?

Comment: Probably nothing-- once you get to `Using local storage: 0` it's out of your hands. As an experiment try rebooting the phone and see if the data uploads afterward.

Comment: If you want to use iCloud, but want it to be 'in your hands', check out Ensembles open source framework (http://ensembles.io). (Disclosure: I am a developer of Ensembles.)

Comment: Rebooting the device doesn't change anything. Nor does changing the name of the database. Searching through Apple's forum, I found some threads on the problem, but there are unsolved. They tend to point to some log file corruption because of MOC access through several threads. The corrupted log files would then confuse iCloud upload. Seems like the "less-worse" investigation way I have so far, because I indeed do work with the MOC from several threads (I thought that was reading only, but...). I'll keep you aware if you are interested.

Comment: Nope. I had every thing in the main queue. SO that's not it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it back to work.
Actually, I did not change anything. But I fully restored the iOS device.
Any explanations will be welcome.

Comment: I currently experienced the same symptom where the devices did received this "Using local storage: 0".  But two devices are not syncing.  I have noticed that everything will work well until if there is an insert/delete record that did not go through.  Then any more actions after that will not go through either.   And That "upload pending stays there forever...".  My conclusion is that iCloud and Core Data are still not working flawlessly.

Comment: Concur.  Struggling with hit or miss behavior myself.  Sometimes the sync simply doesn't occur.